# spyder-2.3.2.amd64-py3.4 can't find python in registry

Tags: python-3.x, installation, spyder

That is the error I receive when I try to install it, even though (windows7) 64bit Python3.4 is clearly installed under C:\Python34.

A workaround is suggested [by /u/juliusc here](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2o6zou/ann_spyder_232_is_released/) to just run "pip3 install spyder" This seems also not to work. Below is the error message I get in this case:

Downloading/unpacking spyder
  Running setup.py (path:C:\cygwin64\tmp\pip_build_cgs567\spyder\setup.py) egg_info for package spyder
    WARNING: unable to build documentation because Sphinx is not installed

```
warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.po' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.qm' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'app_example'
```

Installing collected packages: spyder
  Running setup.py install for spyder
    WARNING: unable to build documentation because Sphinx is not installed

```
warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.po' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.qm' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'app_example'
```

Successfully installed spyder
Cleaning up...

Note this actually creates a spyder BAT file, but running it in the command line  says no such file or directory.

EDIT: This is the error message on pip3 install spyder from the commandline:

Downloading/unpacking spyder
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\cgs567\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_cgs567\spyder\setup.py) egg_info for package spyder
    WARNING: unable to build documentation because Sphinx is not installed

```
warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.po' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.qm' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'app_example'
```

Installing collected packages: spyder
  Running setup.py install for spyder
    WARNING: unable to build documentation because Sphinx is not installed

```
warning: no files found matching '*.pot' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.po' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'spyderlibplugins'
warning: no files found matching '*.' under directory 'doc'
warning: no files found matching '*.bat' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.qm' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.svg' under directory 'app_example'
warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'app_example'
```

Successfully installed spyder
Cleaning up...

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) I don't understand. Did you install Python through Cygwin? If that's the case, even if Python is under `C:\Python34`, I think the Spyder installer won't detect it because Cygwin is a Unix emulation layer that runs on top of Windows. So your Python is not a proper Windows Python installation. That's also (probably) why your pip installation fails. It detects that is running under a Windows system, so it tries to install a bat script file, but since Cygwin is like Linux, it should install a Python script.

Comment: If you want to get things working properly, please install Python using its official Windows installers. We don't plan to support Cygwin, sorry :-(

Comment: Okay some clarification is in order:
1) I did not install python with cygwin. I used python-3.4.2.amd64
2) Yes that error message is from cygwin because I couldn't copy and paste from my command line and the error to my eye seemed identical. cygwin did support copy paste. I realize that was a little disingenuous.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I'd like to say some things: 1) The errors you report are not that important. 2) The Spyder installer should find Python in the Windows registry, so this means you (somehow) didn't install Python correctly. I think this will lead you to further problems later on. 3) You don't need to run the bat file directly, just open a terminal (`cmd.exe`) and run `spyder`, that's all. 4) If you're new to Python, I sincerely recommend you to install a scientific Python distribution (like Anaconda or WinPython), instead of following this procedure :-)

Comment: I forgot to say that both Anaconda and WinPython come with Spyder (and a whole bunch of other scientific libraries) preinstalled.

Comment: I thought about getting a distribution, but it's really important to me to have the 64bit version of python3.4. Do these distributions support that?

Comment: Yes, both WinPython and Anaconda support Windows 64 bits for Python 3. Besides, they will let you update packages (like Pandas or NumPy) to their latest versions quite easily.

Comment: Thanks Carlos. I appreciate all the Spyder question answering you do on SO